# Drawing a custom shape

Tags: android, draw, drawrect

I need to draw a custom shape like the following.
I am trying to draw this on a Canvas for a custom view that i am trying to make. The custom view will represent a fuel level indicator.
Any ideas as to how i can achieve this drawing?

[image]

Comment: see `Canvas#drawPath`

Comment: @Siguza. This is what i have in my mind. Just like the digital fuel indicator that we see in bikes.

Answer (score 0):

Draw what you are asking using [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html), using *moveTo(float x, float y)* ,*lineTo (float x, float y)* and *close()* methods.
The clip the canvas to that path ( using *clipPath (Path path)* method of the [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)  ).

Then to make some of it red, just draw a red rectangle of appropriate height and length.